# How to include an if statement within the javascript of a multiple line innerHTML property?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, svg, innerhtml

I am using java-script to render a dynamic svg based on js variables on my html/php page using the innerHTML property.

It's a complex svg so I have split the string into multiple lines.

My current code works fine;

```
document.getElementById('diagram1').innerHTML 
= '<svg width="'+canvas_width+'" height="'+canvas_height+'">'
+ '<line x1="0" y1="'+depth+'" x2="'+width+'" y2="'+depth+'" stroke="#ff6622" stroke-width="3"></line>'
+ '<rect width="'+svg_width+'" height="'+svg_height+'" x="100" y="140" fill="#CCC"></rect>'
+ '</svg>';
```

However, if I wrap any of the lines in an if statement then that line is never rendered even if the conditions of the if statement are met.

```
document.getElementById('diagram1').innerHTML 
= '<svg width="'+canvas_width+'" height="'+canvas_height+'">'
if (test == 'on') {
+ '<line x1="0" y1="'+depth+'" x2="'+width+'" y2="'+depth+'" stroke="#ff6622" stroke-width="3"></line>'
}
+ '<rect width="'+svg_width+'" height="'+svg_height+'" x="100" y="140" fill="#CCC"></rect>'
+ '</svg>';
```

Is there a different / better way to do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: That is not how you build a string dynamically. I am sure error message in console points it our.

Comment: Console is showing no errors. This is not a particularly helpful comment without any other info. I did ask if there was different / better way to do this so I'm more than happy to hear any explanation you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the string before setting it to `innerHTML`:

```
let text = '<svg width="'+canvas_width+'" height="'+canvas_height+'">';
if (test == 'on') {
    text += '<line x1="0" y1="'+depth+'" x2="'+width+'" y2="'+depth+'" stroke="#ff6622" stroke-width="3"></line>';
}
text += '<rect width="'+svg_width+'" height="'+svg_height+'" x="100" y="140" fill="#CCC"></rect>' + '</svg>';
document.getElementById('diagram1').innerHTML = text;
```

Or you can use ternary:

```
document.getElementById('diagram1').innerHTML
= '<svg width="'+canvas_width+'" height="'+canvas_height+'">'
+ (test == 'on' ? '<line x1="0" y1="'+depth+'" x2="'+width+'" y2="'+depth+'" stroke="#ff6622" stroke-width="3"></line>' : '')
+ '<rect width="'+svg_width+'" height="'+svg_height+'" x="100" y="140" fill="#CCC"></rect>'
+ '</svg>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
document.getElementById('diagram1').innerHTML 
= '<svg width="'+canvas_width+'" height="'+canvas_height+'">' +
(test == 'on' ? 
'<line x1="0" y1="'+depth+'" x2="'+width+'" y2="'+depth+'" stroke="#ff6622" stroke-width="3"></line>'
: '')
+ '<rect width="'+svg_width+'" height="'+svg_height+'" x="100" y="140" fill="#CCC"></rect>'
+ '</svg>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to do the same thing. So if you have any condition, you could include it into your HTML as -

```
`...some html before codition${test === 'on' ? 'when condition is true':null}`
```

Also, template literals would be a better choice in such cases instead of having multiple `+`, you can do the same with template literals in a shorter, more efficient manner.

If you still want to use strings only, you can try using the **ternary operator** in the same way as I did above using template literals. Another choice would be to just split the string over multiple lines and conditionally append you HTML code depending on the conditions you want to apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
let defaultText = '<svg width="'+canvas_width+'" height="'+canvas_height+'">';
let extraText = '<line x1="0" y1="'+depth+'" x2="'+width+'" y2="'+depth+'" stroke="#ff6622" stroke-width="3"></line>';
let endText = '<rect width="'+svg_width+'" height="'+svg_height+'" x="100" y="140" fill="#CCC"></rect>'
+ '</svg>';

document.getElementById('diagram1').innerHTML = test == 'on' ?  defaultText + endText : defaultText + extraText + endText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to store it in a variable and add it to this in your if-clause and later the rest. You didn't builtm the innerHTML proper together all the parts in if and behind are missed so you get trouble with these losing parts.

```
let innerHTML = '<svg width="'+canvas_width+'" height="'+canvas_height+'">';
if (test == 'on') {
  innerHTML += '<line x1="0" y1="'+depth+'" x2="'+width+'" y2="'+depth+'" stroke="#ff6622" stroke-width="3"></line>'
};

innerHTML +=  '<rect width="'+svg_width+'" height="'+svg_height+'" x="100" y="140" fill="#CCC"></rect>'
  + '</svg>';
  
document.getElementById('diagram1').innerHTML;
```